# Java GUI is not modified/updated when called from thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I have a project where I have to create a [roulette wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHRFL.png) using Java Swing. When the wheel is "spun", the numbers on the wheel are [randomly highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxGoA.png) before landing on a final number.

I have to create a GUI class which supplies the JLabels in the above layout. The method for spinning the wheel is also required in this GUI class, and we explicitly must use a thread and the Runnable interface to handle this.

I have been provided with a driver class by the professor, which creates a JFrame and Buttons, before adding the GUI Class (RouletteWheel):

```
public WheelTest()
{
    theWindow = new JFrame("WheelTest Program");
    theWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ActionListener listen = new ButtonListener();

    setButton = new JButton("Set Wheel");  
    setButton.setFont(myFont);
    setButton.addActionListener(listen);

    ........

    theWheel = new RouletteWheel();   //GUI class
    theWindow.add(theWheel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Here is what my GUI class looks like:

```
final RouletteSquare [] squareArray = new RouletteSquare[37];  //Array of JLabels
private Boolean spun;

public RouletteWheel(){
    createGUI();
}

private void createGUI(){  //Creates a RouletteSquare object for each place in the array
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));
    for(int i = 0; i <= 36; i++){
        squareArray[i] = new RouletteSquare(i);
        this.add(squareArray[i]);
        squareArray[i].choose();
    }
}

public void spin(){
    Runnable wheel = new RouletteWheel();
    new Thread(wheel).start();
}

public void run(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    long nanoTime = 10000;
    while(elapsedTime <= nanoTime)
    {
        i = rand.nextInt(37);
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        squareArray[i].choose();  //Highlights square CYAN color
        try {Thread.sleep(500);}  //Adds a delay between selections
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
        squareArray[i].unChoose();  //Un-highlights square
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    }
    i = rand.nextInt(37);
    squareArray[i].choose();
}
```

For the record, this GUI class utilizes another class from a prior project called RouletteSquare, which simply creates an individual JLabel and provides the method for highlighting that JLabel. I use an array of RouletteSquares to create the RouletteWheel (this was also required for this project). Here is what the RouletteSquare class looks like:

```
private boolean cvar;
private int value;
public RouletteSquare(int val)
{
    value = val;
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

    number2 = new JLabel();
    number2.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    number2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
    number2.setForeground(getColorType(getColor()));
    number2.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    number2.setOpaque(true);
    number2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 75));
    this.add(number2);
}

public boolean isChosen() {
    return cVar;
}

public void unChoose() {
    cVar = false;
    number2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public void choose() {
    cVar = true;
    number2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
}
```

The GUI is correctly created & initialized, and I can make changes to it outside of the thread method call.

The problem I'm running into is, as far as I can tell via print statements, my code executes properly, but the GUI does not update when called via the thread. I have tried to use SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(Runnable), but this has been unsuccessful in solving my problem. I cannot use a javax.swing.timer either, as I MUST use a thread.

I'm running out of ideas & am beginning to grow quite frustrated. Any help would be seriously appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your RouletteWheel class:

```
theWheel = new RouletteWheel();
```

but then in your spin() method you create another instance of the RouletteWheel:

```
public void spin(){
    Runnable wheel = new RouletteWheel();
    new Thread(wheel).start();
}
```

You only want a single instance of the RouletteWheel class.

I would guess the code should be:

```
//new Thread(wheel).start();
new Thread(this).start();
```

Comment: Oh my god that worked. Thank you so, so much. I've literally been staring at this for ~5 hours and haven't been able to crack it.